# Mathematical induction proof that $f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> The function $f(n)$ for $n=0,1...$ has the recursive definition $$f(n)= \begin{cases} 2 & \text {for n=0} \\ -f(n-1)+1 & \text{for n=1,2...} \end{cases}$$
>   Prove by induction that the following equation holds: $$f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^n$$

So, I begin by checking that the basic step holds

1. $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^0=2$ OK
2. Assume that the equation holds for a given $n$
3. Show that n+1 holds: $f(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{n+1} \Rightarrow f(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{n} \cdot (-1) = -f(n)-\frac{1}{2}$

I get kind of stuck here. Any advice on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have come close in proving the correct form of $f(n+1)$. We then just need to do one more step. Notice that: $$f(n+1)= \frac12+ \frac32(-1)^{n+1}= (1)-(\frac12 +\frac32(-1)^n) =1-f(n)$$ proving that $f(n+1)$ is also true. The proof is thus finished!

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate of where the $(1)$ comes from in the third part of the equation?

Comment: @Alex5207 Note that we want to prove that $f(n+1)=1-f(n)$. Also, note that $\frac12 = 1- \frac12$. And, $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Alex5207 You can upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Alex5207 Something that helps me to know to even look for that $(1)$ when I get stuck, is to take my desired end result $-f(n) + 1$ and then work backwards and meet in the middle when it matches.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(m+1)=1-f(m)=1-\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac32(-1)^m\right)=1-\dfrac12+\dfrac32(-1)^{m+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your last step is close, but not quite

$$ f(n+1) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}(-1)^n = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2}(-1)^n\right) = -f(n) + 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

$f(n)=1-f(n-1)$. We want to show that

$$f(n+1)=1-f(n)=1-[1-f(n-1)]=f(n-1)$$

$f(n+1)=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}(-1)^n $

$f(n-1)= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2}(-1)^{n-1}$. Multiply this equality $-1$,then

$-f(n-1)= [\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2}(-1)^{n-1}](-1)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^n$. Hence we obtain

$f(n-1)=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}(-1)^n=f(n+1)$